# lsocket library not found on a mac

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I need to do some socket programming on Mac OS X but I'm missing the library for it?
This is what happens when I compile:

```
gcc ser.c -o ser -lsocket -lnsl
ser.c: In function ‘main’:
ser.c:41: warning: format ‘%.24s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 6 has type ‘int’
ld: library not found for -lsocket
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I get this library?

Comment: You get this library by installing OS X.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need `-lsocket` on OS X.